# Why is it a code smell to use any_instance_of in Rspec?

Tags: rspec

There aren't many resources online for this but the closest to the answer is on the relishapp.com website:

> The rspec-mocks API is designed for individual object instances, but
>   this feature operates on entire classes of objects. As a result there
>   are some semantically confusing edge cases. For example, in
>   expect_any_instance_of(Widget).to receive(:name).twice it isn't clear
>   whether a specific instance is expected to receive name twice, or if
>   two receives total are expected. (It's the former.)

But if you are using context/describe blocks correctly to scope the use case then this problem does not exist at all.

Are there any negatives from using this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although using `any_instance` appears to be very handy and easy to use, it does cause confusion as your test suite grows. Method invocation expectations are mostly used for unit style tests where you should have complete control over the dependencies that used by the test subject. If you're using `expect_any_instance_of(Widget)`, then it implies you're not stubbing/mocking the dependencies, and instead allowing code from outside the unit to be executed as part of the test, which somewhat defeats the purpose of unit testing. For higher coverage tests, i.e., acceptance/integration, then you shouldn't be setting expectations on objects, but should be confirming that the system has done what you requested, either by checking output on a webpage, or confirming data was saved to disk.